# Como enviar uma confirmação de e-mail para o usuário registrado através do Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Eu tenho esta rotina de registro e preciso que envie uma confirmação de e-mail quando o usuário se registrar, como posso fazer?

```
// SETUP NEW USER
$data = array(
    'display_name'  => esc_attr($_POST['display_name']),
    'user_login' => esc_attr($_POST['user_login']),
    'user_email' => esc_attr($_POST['email']),
    'user_pass'  => esc_attr($_POST['user_pass']),
    'game_pass'  => esc_attr($_POST['game_pass']),
    'role'       => get_option('default_role'),
);

$new_user = wp_insert_user($data);
wp_new_user_notification($new_user, $user_pass);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para enviar email com o WP você pode fazer desta forma:

```
<?php
$to = "ANDRE.L.OTTO@GMAIL.COM";
$subject = "Learning how to send an Email in WordPress";
$content = "WordPress knowledge";

$status = wp_mail($to, $subject, $content);
```

só adicionar a sua lógica conforme necessidade.